# Why can't this code snippet be synthesized?

Tags: vhdl

```
LIBRARY ieee;       
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;    
ENTITY  simple_buffer   IS      
PORT    (   din :   IN  std_logic;  
                        dout    :   OUT std_logic
);      
END simple_buffer;  
ARCHITECTURE    behavioural1    OF  simple_buffer   IS      
BEGIN       
dout    <=  din AFTER   10  ns;     
END behavioural1;
```

Just like the question asked in the title, WHY can't this code snippet be synthesized?

Comment: It can be synthesised, but the `after` statement will be ignored.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question to add relevant details. Which synthesizer software are you using? What is the complete error message? Copy it as text, please, no screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

It's the concurrent signal assignment:

```
dout <=  din AFTER   10  ns;
```

An FPGA or ASIC has no notion of time, other than that which can be inferred by clocks, or by using delay lines.

You can use a clock with the following construct:

```
dout <= din when rising_edge(clk);
```

You might get away with using a delay line in your FPGA/ASIC technology of choice, but you'll have to look up the capabilities of your chosen target. In that case you will need to instantiate a special, vendor-provided component.